# How to create SOAP api webserices in rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to know whether it is possible to create SOAP APIs in RAILS. I googled and found that SAVON can be used for communicating with SOAP API, is their anyway to create soap apis in rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

We've just released 0.3.2 of https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out with new tiny features. It's currently active and maintained (unlike ActionWebService). And is probably best way to do what you want.

However even being maintainer of such a gem I do not recommend you to use SOAP at all. WashOut was created for the cases where you have no choice. So please think twice. In most cases REST is much more preferable.

Answer (score 1):

There's a gem called actionwebservice that served this purpose many years ago. There are a few people who have maintained it along the way, but you might have to dig around. Searching ruby gems.org brings up a [few results](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=actionwebservice) but it seems like even these are not really maintained. You might want to check out [some of the forks](https://github.com/datanoise/actionwebservice/network) too and see if they are still being maintained.

Having said that, if you have the option to not use SOAP, don't. Use REST as support for it is built into Rails and likely isn't going away any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check this gem - https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out